# How do I reference the managedObjectContext in my App Delegate from my View Controller?

Tags: iphone, core-data, sdk, uitabbarcontroller

I know there are other questions covering this topic, but none seem to fit exactly what I'm experiencing, hence the new question.

I have an app which is a UITabBarController, I have defined two subviews

Both tabs have their Class attribute in the Identity Inspector set to UINavigationController.

Both subviews are Class UIViewController and contain MKMapView objects.

I am trying to integrate Core Data with the objective being that I can use Core Data to store information about object I want to place on the map.

I have my UITabBarController defined as 'rootController' in my Delegate header file.
I also have the managedObjectModel, managedObjectContext and persistentStoreCoordinator properties defined there.

In the Delegate implementation I have the standard accessor methods for the above properties and I have rootController defined as follows:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

[window addSubview:rootController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
```

In my view controllers for the child views, I have defined my managedObjectContext and synthesized it.

Now for my problem, I cannot get the compiler to allow me to reference the managedObjectContext in the App Delegate from the View Controllers.

I tried the following in the applicationDidFinishLaunching method:

```
firstView.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

But I just get the following error:

```
Accessing unknown 'setManagedObjectContext:' class method
```

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Thanks

---

Update:

To add to my question, I'll head off some answers by providing more detail

I have an @Class declaration in my appdelegate.h file
I have a #import statement in my appdelegate.m file for the firstView.h file
I have declared my firstView as follows in my appdelegate.h file

```
FirstView *firstView;
```

Comment: Actually, I found a typo.  I was referencing the Class rather than the  instance in my firstView.managedObjectContext statement.  Compiling without errors now.  Thanks @Gerry3

Comment: Yeah, the fact that the error message you were getting said "class method" was odd, so I was wondering how you using the class rather than an instance of that class. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is `firstView` declared and assigned?

It should be a reference to an object with a property named "managedObjectContext".

Comment: Firstview is a uiviewcontroller. Mamagedobjectcontext is a property of the uiviewController

Comment: @Gerry3 Did you mean how is it defined within the delegate?

Comment: Yes, is it declared as a UIViewController or properly as your custom subclass of UIViewController that actually has the property?

Comment: @Gerry3 Well the only reference to my FirstView code is via an @Class declaration in the delegate header. Do I need to import the header file from FirstView to be able to reference its managedObjectContext property?

Comment: Hmmm, didn't have the source code in front of me earlier @Gerry3.
I already have imported my firstView.h file in the delegate implementation file.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Is firstView declared as a UIViewController though or as your custom subclass? It has to be the latter. Can you edit your question and post more code (like the app delegate header)?

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into this same problem, i'll share my solution.

First you need a reference to the Nav Controller in the Tab Bar in the nib file, make sure you connect it up.

```
IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

Then, get the Controller as recommended in the support docs and send it the managedObjectContext:

```
SavedTableViewController *saved = (SavedTableViewController *)[navigationController topViewController];
saved.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

Alex (from another post) is right, "You should generally stay away from getting shared objects from the app delegate. It makes it behave too much like a global variable, and that has a whole mess of problems associated with it."

Comment: If you only use one view controller to modify objects and the other view controllers to view then sharing objects isn't much of a problem surely?

Comment: You have a good point, but what if you add another view Controller in future that will also access this? Or you want to restructure your app? This method is more about future proofing and make sure you don't run into unnecessary problems down the road. CD was intended for the app delegate to give the context to the controller, not the other way around. It's not my idea of an ideal implementation, but it's what the engineers have recommended, just passing on the message..